# Is there any Information to get default value of stored procedure Input parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, information-schema

Is there any Information to get default value of stored procedure Input parameters is **SQL Server** side?

> I can get information about stored procedure input parameters via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` but this table does not give any info about **Default Value** of the parameters.

Comment: All input parameters to stored procedures are nullable. Only natively compiled stored procedures (for SQL Server 2014) supports non-nullable parameters.

Comment: you can define parameters nullable or not. but I want to know if sql server save this info or not. for example you define a parameter like this : `@FromaDate char(10) = NULL`

Comment: Perhaps you mean default value for parameters as all of them can be null.

Comment: Yes! so Is there any Information to get default value of stored procedure Input parameters? I corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value of each declared parameter must be supplied by the user when the procedure is called, unless a default for the parameter is defined or the value is set to equal another parameter.

And all parameters are null-able as all data-types accept null.
You can don't prompt a parameter by setting a default value to it.

And you can use `sys.parameters` table for seeing default values.